# How do I tag a table in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I've got a huge table for R which should not be exported. So I added a `#TAGS: noexport` above the table, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. So how do I tag a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add tags to a table, only to a header.

Also, the `#+TAGS` directive is used to declare a group of tags specific to the whole document, not for tagging a table.

If you surround the table within a comment block, it will not be exported. For example:

```
#+begin_comment

#+tblname: very_long_table
| col1 | col2 |
|------+------|
| 1    | 22   |
| 2    | 23   |
| 3    | 24   |
| 4    | 25   |
| 5    | 26   |

#+end_comment

#+begin_src sh :var tbl=very_long_table :exports both
echo $tbl
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 1 22 2 23 3 24 4 25 5 26
```