# Org-mode: mark a table as "no export"

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a table that I use to plot the graphs with `#+PLOT:` directive, that sends the plot into the file. In my export I would like to exclude the table but only include the plot. The latter is easy: `[[file:./plot.png]]` does the trick. The former seems to be more difficult. In another example, I use the table to store the parameters for the plot: the plot itself is done using direct gnuplot script with `:var data=param-table :exports result`. Once again, I don't want the table.

I have two partial solutions:

1. If the table is generated from a source code script, I just put `:exports none` for the script. Works well. But what if the table is not generated by a script?
2. Potentially, I can move the table into a subtree that is marked `:noexport:`, but it is nice (and more logical) to have it close to where the plotting is done or I would have to introduce unnecessary low-level headings.

Is there in Org-mode perhaps a marker like `#+NOEXPORT` of sort, that I can place before the table to prevent it from exporting?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582469/how-do-i-tag-a-table-in-org-mode): embed the table inside a `comment` block.

Comment: @Juancho this does the trick: tables are still "referencible" by other parts of org-document, but are not exported.

Comment: @Juancho Actually, after reviewing this solution, it does not work: when the table appears inside the comment block, it is no longer accessible by other blocks (like source code). But to see this (negative) effect, had to restart Emacs.